SQL Server and App Service connectivity across subscriptions
I have two subscriptions, we will call them A and B. Subscription A has an app service that should only be accessible via private endpiont (user's will VPN into the environment via P2S). Subscription B has a SQL Server with a few DB's the app service needs connectivity to. I have created a private endpoint on the app service side, with a private dns zone, and I have done the same on the SQL server side. I also configured VNet integration on the app service side, and connected it directly to the VNet SQL server is on in subscription B.
My understanding is the private endpoint with an app service is only for inbound connections, while the vnet integration would be for outbound. Next, I went to the private dns zone in Subscription A for the app service, and linked it to the SQL Servers VNet in subscription B. In my head, this should give the SQL server connectivity to the app service inbound via private link service without the need for a VNET peer, and the VNet integration should work for outbound as the app service is directly integrated with the SQL servers VNET.
when testing, I am still unable to get connectivity from resource to resource. What am I missing? Do I need to add the app settings similar to what is mentioned here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/access-to-web-app-behind-a-private-endpoint/m-p/2122208/highlight/true#M215
